# If there are basis $B$ and $B'$ s.t. $[T]_{BB}=[T^{-1}]_{B'B'}$ does $Spec(T)\cap\{ l\mid |l|<1\}\neq\emptyset\iff $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a $\mathbb C-$vector space of finite dimension. Let $T\in \mathcal L(V)$ invertible. If there exist basis $B$ and $B'$ of $V$ s.t. $$[T]_{BB}=[T^{-1}]_{B'B'}$$ does $$Spec(T)\cap\{ \lambda \mid |\lambda |<1\}\neq\emptyset\iff Spec(T)\cap\{ \lambda \mid |\lambda |>1\}\neq\emptyset,$$
where $Spect(T)$ is the set of eigenvalues.

---

I know that $[T^{-1}]_{B'B'}=[T^{-1}]_{B'B'}$, and thus $$[T]_{BB}[T]_{B'B'}=1.$$

Therefore, as matrices, $[T]_{B'B'}$ is the inverse of $[T]_{BB}$. Moreover, if $\lambda \in Spect(T)$ then $\frac{1}{\lambda }\in Spect(T^{-1})$. Therefore, $$\lambda v=[T]_{BB}v=[T^{-1}]_{B'B'}v=\frac{1}{\lambda }v\implies (\lambda ^2-1)v=0\implies \lambda ^2=1$$
since eigenvectors are $\neq 0$. We conclude that $\lambda =\pm 1$ what is a contradiction.

I'm not sure that I'm doing well. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Be careful, writing $[T]_{BB}v=[T]_{B'B'}v$ really don't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $[\mathcal T]_{B,B} = [\mathcal T^{-1 }]_{B',B'}$, then $[\mathcal T]_{B,B}$ is similar to $[\mathcal T^{-1}]_{B,B}$, hence $\mathrm {Spec} (\mathcal T) = \mathrm {Spec} (\mathcal T^{-1})$. Since $\lambda \in \mathrm {Spec} (\mathcal T) \iff \lambda ^{-1} \in \mathrm {Spec} (\mathcal T^{-1}) = \mathrm {Spec}(\mathcal T)$, the assertion is correct.

In different bases, the matrix of  eigenvectors are different.

Answer (score 0):

Careful, the eigenvalues are invariant, but not the eigenvectors.

I would solve it like this: The eigenvalues are independent of the basis, and hence, by your observation, in our situation the spectrum is closed under inversion.